# Позиционирование с флексбоксов

Tags: html, css

Не могу правильно с помощью флексбока спозиционировать текст по отношению к футболке как показано на скриншоте[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide"
    });
});
```

```css
ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.kofta{
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: 65px;
}

.logotype{
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    top: 65px;
}

.kofta-1{
    width: 50%;
}

.texst{
  width: 50%;  
}

.flexslider {
  height: 445px;
  background: #40c7ba;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  height: auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.flex-viewport {
  height: 445px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.loading .flex-viewport {
  max-height: 300px;
}
.carousel li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.flex-direction-nav {
  *height: 0;
}
.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    left: -50px;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    right: -50px;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: -1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}
.flex-pauseplay a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.flex-pauseplay a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before {
}
.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
  position: relative;
  top: -68px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  background: 
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #77d3cb;
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-thumbs {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * RESPONSIVE
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="slider">
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="first-slide">
     <div class="kofta-1">
      <img class="kofta" src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/16/4c5204c7ef78a0f60adbba872f31239b-full.png">
      </div>
      <div class="texst">
      <h1>Cowhide<br> 
          Standard Crew</h1>
          <p>White coloured, short-sleeved, printed T-shirt for<br>
           men by Levi's. This crew-neck T-shirt is made of<br>
            organic cotton and comes in a regular fit. </p>
            </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

У меня же просто не получается даже с места его сдвинуть [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте завернуть ваш `img` в `div`, и дайте этому блоку ширину 50% , как и блоку в котором лежит текст.

Comment: И честно говоря, не вижу в вашей верстке ни одного флексбокса, так что метка `flexbox` тут не совсем уместна

Comment: @Klimenkomud Можно вопрос, у меня сильно корявая вёрстка да?

Comment: если честно, хотел оформить ответ, но у тя в коде, сам черт ногу сломит.... на кой тебе префиксы? без них уже во всех браузерах все работает, я не помню случая, что бы понадобились префиксы.

Comment: @Air Та блин просто новичок во всём этом, и учился верстать по видео 2013 года, и да что такое префиксы?

Comment: -webkit- , -moz-, вот это называется префиксы

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2Y5oFgmm20&t=185s    посмотри это видео и сам все сделаешь

Comment: @Air Ага спасибо, и если можно ещё один вопрос. Я так понимаю на флотах уже не кто давно не верстает да?

Comment: вопрос можно, нельзя только спрашивать, "можно ли еще вопрос", мы тут все и сидим, что-бы опытом делиться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67218/discussion-between-brafik-and-air).

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

*(css код в конце + у вас был 1 не закрытый див)*

```js
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
//$(window).load(function() {
//  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
//    animation: "slide"
//  });
//});
```

```css
/*Slider*/

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.kofta {
  position: relative;
  left: 180px;
  top: 65px;
}

.logotype {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: 65px;
}

.flexslider {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 445px;
  background: #40c7ba;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}

.flexslider .slides img {
  height: auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}

.flex-viewport {
  height: 445px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.loading .flex-viewport {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.carousel li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.flex-direction-nav {
  *height: 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -50px;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -50px;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 10px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 10px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: -1;
}

.flex-pauseplay a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}

.flex-pauseplay a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.flex-pauseplay a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before {}

.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
  position: relative;
  top: -68px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  background: cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #77d3cb;
  cursor: default;
}

.flex-control-thumbs {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}


/* ====================================================================================================================
     * RESPONSIVE
     * ====================================================================================================================*/

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 10px;
  }
}

/*new*/
.first-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.kofta {
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.texst {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="slider">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="first-slide">
        <img class="kofta" src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/16/4c5204c7ef78a0f60adbba872f31239b-full.png">
        <div class="texst">
          <h1>Cowhide<br> Standard Crew</h1>
          <p>White coloured, short-sleeved, printed T-shirt for<br> men by Levi's. This crew-neck T-shirt is made of<br> organic cotton and comes in a regular fit. </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: точнее не открытый див

Comment: у меня почему-то перестал сам слайдер работать

Comment: Вы просили помочь сверстать слайд. Про работу слайдера ничего не написали. У вас в примере не добавлен плагин который эту работу выполняет, поэтому выползает ошибка на пол экрана, которая мешает дебажить, поэтому весь js я закомментировала.

Comment: Учите мат часть. Просто копирование кода может привести вас в неловкую ситуацию, раз уж делаете - надо разбираться.

Comment: сори  у меня всё начало работать, я просто кое что не досмотрел

Comment: Вы не обижайтесь) раз уж просите сделать на флекс боксах, то и принимайте ответ во флексбоксах, а не во флоатах)

Comment: Ваше решение мне нравится больше, вопрос в другом: человек думает что слайдер с названием `flexslider` сделан на флексбоксах, а на самом деле - это не так, обычный флоатный слайдер. Я дал решение, соответствующее "стилю" этой библиотеки.

Comment: @kizoso Хорошо я принял

Comment: @Klimenkomud я кажется понял, спасибо за ответ, теперь я потихоньку начинаю въезжать в эту тему

Comment: @BraFik Всегда пожалуйста =)

Comment: @Klimenkomud Да, скорее всего вы правы

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<div class="slider">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="first-slide">
        <div class="img-block"><img class="kofta" src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/16/4c5204c7ef78a0f60adbba872f31239b-full.png"></div>       
        <div class="texst">
          <h1>Cowhide<br> Standard Crew</h1>
          <p>White coloured, short-sleeved, printed T-shirt for<br> men by Levi's. This crew-neck T-shirt is made of<br> organic cotton and comes in a regular fit. </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

.img-block {
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
.kofta {
  position: relative;
}
.texst {
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Вроде бы на флекс боксах просили, а вы на флоатах сделали..